# Updating multiple rows at once in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text file which contains for example company names, products, and prices. There is about 200 records in the db and little more in the text file. Now I would like to update all prices to db by one sql query. I have tried this:

```
for($i = $start_row; $i < $stop_row; $i += 3)
...
$prices = array($price1, $price2, price3);
$pricesfloat = array_map('floatval', $prices);
...
$query = "UPDATE test3 SET price1 = $pricesfloat[0], price2 = $pricesfloat[1], price3 = $pricesfloat[2] WHERE company = '$company' AND product = '$product'";
mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

`mysql_affected_rows()` returns 0 rows. I can insert all values to db with INSERT INTO, but in this case I must update existing values and add missing values later. Could someone help? :)

Comment: Maybe REPLACE sql-query can help you?

Comment: If I remember right, `REPLACE`-statement not support `WHERE`

Comment: Yes, you can try add UNIQUE super-indexe(company + product) and then use REPLACE IGNORE

Comment: Note that mysql_affected_rows might return 0 even if the update was successful. This is when old values and new values are same.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html, may suit you situation:

```
INSERT INTO table (product_id, price) VALUES (1, 1.323),(2, 3434) ... (200, 2.333) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price = VALUES(price)
```

Another way of bulk update is:

```
UPDATE table
INNER JOIN (
    (SELECT 'company1' AS company, 'product1' AS product, 'price1' AS price
    UNION ALL SELECT 'company2', 'product2', 'price2'
    ....
    UNION ALL SELECT 'companyN', 'productN', 'priceN') AS tmp 
) USING (company, product)
SET table.price = tmp.price
```

Comment: I am not sure can I get that working, because the database doesn't have IDs to product and companys, there is just ID for each row. And the plan is that matching rows must have update and if there is not added data, php script asks user what to do if matches not found.

Comment: You may add unique index on (company, product) to have duplicate collision. Or use tricky update with union-generated derived table :)

Comment: I tried to add unique index to company but I got message 'Duplicate entry error'. Should I do something with record's ID? It is primary key, of course...